# File.dataDirectory not working in Ionic 2

Tags: javascript, cordova, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

While accessing file system using ionic 2 ,
  `File.dataDirectory` is not working . i have installed `ionic-native` and imported `File` (`cordova-plugin-file`).

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController,Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import {Camera,Dialogs,File,Cordova} from 'ionic-native';
```

but 
 am getting this error on VS Code (am using VS code editor) and build also failing..

```
var dir = File.dataDirectory;
```

> Property 'dataDirectory' does not exist on type 'typeof File'

interesting fact is that i can use

`File.createDir` ,

```
File.resolveLocalFilesystemUrl
```

etc...

but `File.dataDirectory` is not working

am using windows as platform and testing on Windows 10 PC .

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Do you have a solution yet?

Comment: @bastifix not yet

Comment: finally I tried npm cache clean and then npm install -g npm@latest and it's working for me now - maybe it's working for you too ;-)

Comment: The ionic-native code base has the static definition: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-native/blob/master/src/plugins/file.ts#L386 but it just doesn't work in code??? I have the same problem, if I try File.dataDirectory typescript does not recognise it as a property of the File class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a thread on the ionic forums, to find the "actual" answer, and here it is....

In short (so as not to run afoul of the SO moderation zealots) you need to compile up and copy across a new version of ionic-native into your current ionic2 build, see more here:

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/file-datadirectory-static-in-ionic-native-can-not-be-found-by-typescript/83200/2?u=andmar8

Answer (score 0):

try : `declare var cordova: any;` after the import . And use it in your function like this `cordova.file.dataDirectory`